# GCP reCAPTCHA Enterprise key working in dev but not in test or prod

Tags: azure, google-cloud-platform, captcha

Created reCAPTCHA credentials and key etc, plugged into dev env and all worked fine, used the same key in test env and not working, all env running on azure, missing anything obvious?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A reCAPTCHA key is normally tied to a set of individual domains or package names. For web users, the API key pair is unique to the domains and first-level subdomains that you specify. Specifying more than one domain while creating in console,could come in handy if you serve your website from multiple top level domains.